# Converting an array into a string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've been stuck on this for a little while now. Am sure there is an easy solution for this but I am still wrapping my head around php.

I want to get some data from a DB and save it into another.

Using SQL I managed to get that data and save it in an array. Now I want to convert that data into a string to save to a different array (if there is a way to do that directly without first saving into an array, then I am all ears).

I get my data in this format.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 414208 [InterestedEntityId] => 414208 [1] => 126.61370996251785 [Score] => 126.61370996251785 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 479516 [InterestedEntityId] => 479516 [1] => 73.531040944194 [Score] => 73.531040944194 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4129769 [InterestedEntityId] => 4129769 [1] => 54.390965049372674 [Score] => 54.390965049372674 )
```

I want to convert it into:

```
414208  126.61370996251785
479516  73.531040944194  
4129769 54.390965049372674
```

Here is my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT Id, Score FROM users.`table1` WHERE UserId= $userID", $dbh1);

$table = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    $table[] = $row;

$table = implode($table);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(table) VALUES ('$table')", $dbh2);
```

Can someone please help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach loop would do the job.

**Making a nice table:**

```
$output = '<table border="1">';
foreach($table as $row){
    $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td></tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

**Plain text:**

```
$output = '';
foreach($table as $row){
    $output .= $row[0].' '.$row[1].'<br>';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: it should be $output .= $row[0].' '.$row[1] . '<br>'; (you forgot . before <br> )but other than that it's perfect. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet.

```
 <?php
   try
   {
        $a=array(array(414208,126.61370996251785),array(414208,126.61370996251785));
        $string='';
        foreach($a as $key=>$value)
        {
           if(!is_array($value))
           {
              throw new Exception('Not an array.');
            }
           else
           {
            $string=join(' ',$value);
           }        
           }
      }
     catch(Exception $e)
    {
   echo $e->getMessage();
    }    
   echo $string;

 ?>
```